# Minimum volume size for FAT16

Tags: filesystems, embedded, fat16

What are the theoretical and practical **minimum** sizes for a FAT16 volume?

I'm trying to determine the smallest Flash-chip size that can handle a FAT16 FS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly it's 4.1MiB (1,048,576 bytes*4.1 = 4,299,161.6 bytes).

Comment: That's correct. It is either 4.1MiB or equivalently 4.3MB. If you would also like the max size, it is (on a NT/2000/WinXP machine) 4GiB or 4.29GB.

Comment: Ah!  So it makes sense that my FAT driver throws error at about 4MB.  Where does the 4.1 come from?

Comment: The minimum number of sectors is 8401, so the correct minimum byte count (sector size = 512 bytes) is actually 4,301,312. That gives 4.10205078125 MiB.

Answer (score 1):

4.1 MiB [is correct](http://books.google.ca/books?id=jGBerMSdxF4C&pg=RA1-PA1303&lpg=RA1-PA1303&dq=fat16+minimum&source=bl&ots=CnKo2--kOc&sig=pwjXmhRh7sP5bi0Gp3N8cAKzAuY&hl=en&ei=xtoKS93wM8-LlAerpcWFBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CCkQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=fat16%20minimum&f=false), however you could go smaller with FAT12, which is still readable by modern OS's.

Comment: I would, though I hear implementing a FAT12 driver is not easy.